# What are the poles and zeros of the Euler Beta function?

Tags: special-functions, beta-function

1. For what pairs of complex values $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ does the Euler Beta function $B(x,y)$ equal zero?
2. For what pairs of complex values $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ does the Euler Beta function $B(x,y)$ have a pole, and what are the orders of the poles?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: My  first guess would be to use the expression in term of $\Gamma$ and things like the reflection formula ($\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)-\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi s}$ is entire and bounded) to find its zeros/poles, if someone knows a more elementary way I would be glad to know it. Also the zeros/poles of a meromorphic function of two complex variables are (almost) analytic curves, not isolated points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Beta function can be defined by
$$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
So it has zeroes where the denominator tends to $\infty$ in absolute value. The Gamma function tends to an infinite absolute value only when the argument is a negative integer or zero, hence we need
$$x+y\in\mathbb{Z}_{\le0}$$
$$x,y\in\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_{\le0}$$
There are infinitely many such choices including $x=k\in\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}_{\le0}$, $y=-k$.